# Kotlin and Firebase read and write data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have learned Kotlin for 3 weeks so I would like to read the data from my Firebase database.

This is the MainActivity.kt to write the data.

```
val database = Firebase.database
val latitude = latitude.text.toString().toDouble()
    val reflatitude = database.getReference("/user/time/$currenttime/latitude")

    //saved location to the Firebase Database
    reflatitude.setValue(latitude)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Saved the diary latitude to Firebase Database")
        }
```

It worked well, but when I want to call it from another activity such as MapActivity. It still have some problems.

```
val database = Firebase.database
val reflatitude = database.getReference("/user/time/$currenttime/latitude")
reflatitude.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener){
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot){
            val latitude= dataSnapshot.getValue<Double>()
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
        }
    }
```

My Ref does not work in reading the data.

The errors I get:

> - Expecting a class body
> - Too many arguments for @NonNull public open fun addValueEventListener(@NonNull p0: ValueEventListener): ValueEventListener defined in com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
> - Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'
> - No type arguments expected for fun getValue(): Any?
> - Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'
> - Cannot access 'TAG': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'AppCompatActivity'

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Expecting a class body

Comment: Too many arguments for @NonNull public open fun addValueEventListener(@NonNull p0: ValueEventListener): ValueEventListener defined in com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference

Comment: Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'

Comment: No type arguments expected for fun getValue(): Any?

Comment: Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'

Comment: Cannot access 'TAG': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'AppCompatActivity'

Comment: Are you sure your app is connected to firebase?

Comment: Do you want an example of reading and writing data in Firebase?

Comment: Yes, I have checked on the Firebase Console.

Comment: I already have one.

Comment: @5f25d18ce535c81dee73be07fafce5 The number of comments you're posting in a row reduces readability. Note that you can edit comments for 5 minutes, and can always edit your question to add additional information or clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    val database = Firebase.database
    val reflatitude = database.getReference("/user/time/$currenttime/latitude")
    reflatitude .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener { 
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot){
                val latitude= dataSnapshot.getValue<Double>()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I have one error left that is "Cannot access 'TAG': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'AppCompatActivity'"

Comment: Define your TAG in class not in function@5f25d18ce535c81dee73be07fafce5

Comment: While this answered the question, code blocks on their own are not always usually useful answers. It's recommended to explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answered the question.

Comment: Yes, he had a small issue that this answer solved that@Alex Mamo

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin What was that "small issue"? Please edit your answer and provide that information.