# How can I get data to put into an ArrayList using two Firebase ValueEventListeners?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

This is just simple app for music. When searching in the `SearchActivity`, I want the composer's name and song title to be searched and listed together. Here is my Realtime Database in Firebase.

```
- Artists
    - 1
        - image : "Maroon 5's image"
        - name : "Maroon 5"
    - 2
        - image : "Ruel's image_2"
        - name : "Ruel"
    ...

- Songs
    - 1
        - album : "Speak Your Mind (Deluxe)"
        - image : "album's image"
        - name : "Anne-Marie"
        - title : "2002"
        - url : "song's url"
    - 2
        - album : "On My Way"
        - image : "album's image"
        - name : "Alan Walker & Sabrina Carpenter & Farruko"
        - title : "On My Way"
        - url : "song's url"
    ...
```

I tried to access those two databases in android studio, but the data result in ArrayList(=**array**) was always null. Here is my kotlin code in `SearchActivity` when click the button *SEARCH*.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Artists").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

    }

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        for (artist in p0.children) {
            val model = artist.getValue(Artist::class.java)
            model?.let { array.add(Model(it)) }
        }
    }
})

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRefernce("Songs").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListner {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

    }

    override fun onDataChanged(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        for (song for p0.children) {
            val model = song.getValue(Song::class.java)
            model?.let { array.add(Model(it)) }
        }
    }
})

adapter = SearchAdapter(this@SearchActivity, array)
recyclerView.adapter = adpater
```

Is it possible to access two databases and get an array value without a null value? I know that `onDatachanged()` happens late, but is it possible to put the value in the array and then put it in the adapter? I would appreciate it if you let me know in Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Can you replace the schematic representation with the actual JSON of your database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: See my answer here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Comment: So you want to search the `Artist` node and the `Songs` node at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I'm sorry; I got a solution. Solution is just add ````` adapter.notifyDataSetChange()```` in all `````onDataChange()``` method. In this way, I can get data from two database in firebase. Thank you for all your comment!