# Firebase - How do I insert a new child into my Users node on click?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert a new child called "Applied Jobs" to my Users node in Firebase like so:

[image]

However I want this child to be added AFTER clicking a button on the screen called "Request For Hire". I tried the following code by looking at other similar questions but to no avail. I would appreciate it if someone helped me with this. Also to note, I need the child to be added to the current user signed in.

This is my code so far:

JobInfo.java

```
package com.example.oddsynew;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class JobInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView jobName, jobCharge, jobLocation, jobDate, jobTime, jobDesc, jobTasks, addPref, recruiterName;
    ImageView profPic;
    String jobname, jobloc, jobcharge, profpic, startdate, enddate, starttime, endtime, jobdesc, jobtasks, addpref, recruitername, userID;
    ImageButton menuIcon;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    Button requestForHireBtn;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser u;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_info);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        menuIcon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
        requestForHireBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestForHireBtn);

        menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        jobName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobName_info);
        jobCharge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobCharge_info);
        jobLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobLocation_info);
        profPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prof_pic_info);
        jobDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobDate_info);
        jobTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobTime_info);
        jobDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobDesc);
        jobTasks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobTasks);
        addPref = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.additionalPref);
        recruiterName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recruiterName_info);

        jobname = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobName");
        jobloc = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobLocation");
        jobcharge = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobCharge");
        profpic = getIntent().getStringExtra("profPic");
        startdate = getIntent().getStringExtra("startDate");
        enddate = getIntent().getStringExtra("endDate");
        starttime = getIntent().getStringExtra("startTime");
        endtime = getIntent().getStringExtra("endTime");
        jobdesc = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobDesc");
        jobtasks = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobTasks");
        addpref = getIntent().getStringExtra("addPref");
        recruitername = getIntent().getStringExtra("recruiterName");

        jobName.setText(jobname);
        jobCharge.setText(jobcharge);
        jobLocation.setText(jobloc);
        jobDate.setText(startdate + " - " + enddate);
        jobTime.setText(starttime + " - " + endtime);
        jobDesc.setText(jobdesc);
        jobTasks.setText(jobtasks);
        addPref.setText(addpref);
        recruiterName.setText(recruitername);

        Picasso.get().load(profpic).into(profPic);

        requestForHireBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                u = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                userID = u.getUid();
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("userID").child("Applied Jobs");
                myRef.child("job_name").setValue(jobname);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: My answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I read your answer but I'm not sure how I can use it for my problem. It would be nice if you could elaborate since I'm a beginner.

Comment: Your getReference shouldn't be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. All I had to do was to add " mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();" and it worked:

```
requestForHireBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); //added this
                u = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                userID = u.getUid();
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Applied Jobs");
                myRef.child("job_name").setValue(jobname);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("userID").child("Applied Jobs");
myRef.child("job_name").setValue(jobname);
```

into this:

```
userID = u.getUid();
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Applied Jobs");
myRef.child("job_name").setValue(jobname);
```

Remove the quotations around `userID` you have to pass the value. Not String format of userID

Comment: Oh my bad, changed it. But the child doesn't gets added still.

Comment: what does `Log.i(TAG,userID)` give you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use tag. I added that statement but it says "tag manager not found". Could you tell me how to use it?

Comment: just do System.out.println(userID) and check what you get

Comment: I/System.out: [com.example.oddsynew.Job@1cdb547, com.example.oddsynew.Job@dbc0174, com.example.oddsynew.Job@536269d, com.example.oddsynew.Job@2407712]

Comment: Its okay, I got the solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: okay if the answer helped you, please mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("oddsy-b8336").child("Users").child(userID).child("Applied Jobs"); 
myRef.child("job_name").setValue(jobname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userID).child("Applied Jobs"); 
    myRef.child("job_name").setValue(jobname);
```