# Can't get the Children in my firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase database]

I'm trying to get these values in the node panadol and profinal. but it's not working.
I was able to get the date successfully. Here's my code

```
for(final String id: MedicinesListActivity.orderIdsList){

        //get the date of the order
        DatabaseReference dateReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Orders").child(id);
        dateReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //date
                String date = dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                Log.i("Date", date);

                //loop through all the products in the specific order id
                for(DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.child(MedicinesListActivity.userId).child("panadol").getChildren()){
                    Order order = s.getValue(Order.class);
                    Log.i("Item_Name", ""+ order.getName());
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

MedicineListActivity.orderIds -> contains all the orderIds i want to loop through
and the class `Order` contains the name and the orderQuantity.
But it's not working.

Comment: What is the value of `id` in `.child(id)`?

Comment: The orderId @AlexMamo

Comment: Is the right one, `-M4y...`?

Comment: yes it is @AlexMamo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Orders").child(id).child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String orderQuantity = ds.child("orderQuantity").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + "/" + orderQuantity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
panadol/3.0
profinal/2.0
```

Or using the `Order` class:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Orders").child(id).child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Order order = ds.getValue(Order.class);
            Log.d("TAG", ds.getName() + "/" + ds.getOrderQuantity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result will be the same.

In both cases, you have to use all node names in your reference to be able to display that data.

Comment: Thank you Alex :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like under each user's node, you have a list of named products (panadol, profinal). Your code looks up one named product `panadol` in that list with `dataSnapshot.child(MedicinesListActivity.userId).child("panadol")`:

```
//loop through all the products in the specific order id
for(DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.child(MedicinesListActivity.userId).child("panadol").getChildren()){
    Order order = s.getValue(Order.class);
    Log.i("Item_Name", ""+ order.getName());
}
```

Since you then iterate over the child nodes of `panadol`, your `s` snapshot refers to the individual properties of `panadol`: `name` and `orderQuantity`. But your code seems to try to map each of those properties to an entire `Order` object, which won't work.

You have two options:

- Show the individual properties, without using the `Order` class:

  ```
  for(DataSnapshot propSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child(MedicinesListActivity.userId).child("panadol").getChildren()){
      Log.i("Item_Name", propSnapshot.getKey() + "="+ propSnapshot.getValue());
  }
  ```
- Don't use the loop, and get the products and their properties in an `Order` object:

  ```
  for(DataSnapshot propSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child(MedicinesListActivity.userId).getChildren()){
      Order order = s.getValue(Order.class);
      Log.i("Item_Name", propSnapshot.getKey() + "="+ propSnapshot.getValue());
  }
  ```