# How to add data from Firebase Database to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, android-spinner

I want to get data from my Firebase database into a spinner.
I am currently trying to understand how you add data from Firebase into an arrayList.
My firebase database looks like this:

ReusableItems
-- Items
----- 1 : Coffee cup
----- 2 : Water bottle

Currently I'm trying to do the addValueEventListener() method but I don't understand why I'm doing this and I don't understand why it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
    private FirebaseDatabase myDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Spinner mySpinner;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myRef = myDatabase.getReference("ReusableItems").child("Items")
    mySpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

But I need to input the data from Firebase into the arrayList 'items' otherwise the spinner isn't populated by anything. Can someone please help?

Comment: See my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin that is Kotlin, this is Java.

Comment: No matter, they are similar. It will be what you want if it would be in Java?