# Problem reading data from Firebase Realtime Database in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working for training purposes with Kotlin in Android, and I have problems any time I try to access to the data currently in the Firebase Database. Here is the data in the database:

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s3sm.png)

After, I just created a main activity with all required imports after linking application with Firebase, but unfortunately, any time I execute the app and press the button, nothing happens.

```
private lateinit var userReference : DatabaseReference
lateinit var textView : TextView
lateinit var button : Button


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textView = findViewById(R.id.test)
    button = findViewById(R.id.test2)
    button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
            Log.d("IPP", "Im here now...")

            userReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.d("ipp", p0.message)
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("Ipp", "Im in the onDataChange")
                    for (childDataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                        Log.d("Ipp",childDataSnapshot.key) }
                }

            })
        }

    })
}
```

The log is not appearing any time, and it is really annoying, as I search across the documentation and as far as I know, it's everything I should do (I've also checked the rules in the database, and read/write is true always).

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the only Log which is appearing when it is executed is "Im here now...", the one after clicking on the button which is working.

EDIT 2: The rules in the database are set to allow read/write to everyone now just for testing purposes. [Rules in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCOvO.png)

Comment: Is your `onDataChange` even triggered?

Comment: please can you print photo for your database

Comment: Seems like not, and that's why I'm surprised.

Comment: You have the photo already in the post, you should be able to see it from the link I've included Ahmed

Comment: Each of your log messages are capitalised differently. You also don't handle the case where the data is empty (check `p0.hasChildren()`). I'd also consider making the event listener into it's own variable as in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#kotlinktx_4) - maybe the garbage collector is acting up.

Comment: ok please on button and then change that item from database firebase and tell me if it trigger

Comment: change your database rules to true

Comment: Also make sure you did configure the [RTDB rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/rules) and not the [Firestore rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/firestore/rules).

Comment: Currently, I'm not handling the case where the data is empty as I was finally trying to just print something, due to I think it is not going in the function onDataChange.

Comment: I tried to change the data after pressing the button but it is still happening the same. So, I'm starting to think there is no connection from Firebase. Regarding to the rules, yes, I've checked I included the rules in the RTDB instead of the Firestore rules.

Comment: did you enabled your internet permission in your manifest file ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén yes, I've included in the manifest file "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@peter-haddad
peter is right but i will explain if you need it or for someone will find that solution one a day 
here is the default rule for database firebase making it false to prevent unauthorized user to access your database so change it for now to true for both read and wright but when work on release version please make it false and make login or registration for user

Comment: That's the first thing I reviewed, as I it weird, but my current rules are set as true.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the logic, you are getting the same instance  each time you press the button, move the initialization of the `DatabaseReference` outside the button, and also your listeners, because they are listening inside the button

```
  userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
 button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
          
            Log.d("IPP", "I'm here now...")

          
        }

    })

userReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.d("ipp", p0.message)
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("Ipp", "I'm in the onDataChange")
                    for (childDataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                        Log.d("Ipp",childDataSnapshot.key) }
                }

            })
```

Now, each time you add a value inside Users reference, your `addValueEventListener` will trigger, you can test this setting a value inside Users from your button click.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Gastón. I followed your approach you mentioned with unsuccessfull outcome. The issue I encountered, is even with this the data is not added in the Database:https://imgur.com/VHq45pa

What should be the approach if I want to read the data just once instead of have a Listener over the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
private lateinit var userReference : DatabaseReference
lateinit var textView : TextView
lateinit var button : Button


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textView = findViewById(R.id.test)
    button = findViewById(R.id.test2)
    button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").getReference("0") <-------- add this
            Log.d("IPP", "Im here now...")

            userReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.d("ipp", p0.message)
                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("Ipp", "Im in the onDataChange")
                    for (childDataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                        Log.d("Ipp",childDataSnapshot.key) }
                }

            })
        }

    })
}
```

add .getReference("0")