# Write new Integer Data in Firebase Database Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying since yesterday to add a value to my Firebase Database, I have tried several methods but I cannot do it.

When the user looks at a RewardedAD this call addCard which is supposed to add to the current user 1 card, and each time it adds a card to him without deleting the value.

**this is my code for the RewardedAd** (*the Ad show correctly*) :

```
@Override
public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem reward) {
// User earned reward.
addCard();
```

**And this is addCard :**

```
private void addCard() {
    FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Integer carte = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                mutableData.setValue(carte + 1);

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: mutableData.setValue("${carte+1}")

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I just tried but nothing happens on the database side :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin the code in Kotlin, is for read Data ? because I would write Data ^^

Comment: In that question code, you can find writing data

Comment: are u using realtime database or firestore?

Comment: check if mDatabase is initiliazed correctly

Comment: @NullByte08 I use Realtime database ;)

Comment: @NullByte08 I just checked, yes the database is properly initialized. But should the "carte" field already be created in database? or the code can create it all automatically?

Comment: mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("carte")

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Okay it's work but I need to create "carte" before in Database, is there a way to create the "carte" field if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin The new Answer Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476408/app-crash-after-remove-value-of-firebase-database

Sry for the double-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid())` in your code with `mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("carte")` It will be created

Comment: .("carte") or .child("carte") ? I tried without creating the "carte" field in the database, its does not create it, but if I create before it works: /

Comment: .child("carte") @VictorAppercé

Answer (score 0):

**I guess you are trying to create the filed of it doesn't exist through transaction**

**Maybe this is what your structure should look like:**

```
users
|
|-----------UID
             |
             ---card : 1 //and you want to keep updating this
```

**Try this:**

```
private void addCard() {
    FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();

mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("card").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Integer card = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);

         if(card == null){
          //if no card exist yet start with 1
          mutableData.setValue(1);  
          return Transaction.success(mutableData);

         }else{
         //there is card just increment it +1
         mutableData.setValue(card + 1);

         }


        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
});
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I have solve my issue when creating the Field Carte in register ^^ and it's work but, now I try to delete number of Carte when user use NumberPicker in alertDialog, it works but I don't know why my app crash when I remove value of  Carte, but it's works.

Comment: It must be some other problem, in your code and thus another question. But if the above code worked for you it must be the solution for your problem, anything else I guess you must ask a new question.