# App crash after remove value of Firebase Database

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem when I try removing values of firebase database, It's works correctly but my app still crashing :/

So I managed to get the code to work which adds a value to "Carte".

But now I'm trying with a NumberPicker to remove a certain number of Carte and add entries to something else.

**Here is my code which adds entries with a loop.**

```
if (i == R.id.ParticipCarte1) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
        np.setMinValue(1);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Integer nbrcarte = dataSnapshot.child("carte").getValue(Integer.class);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    np.setMaxValue(nbrcarte);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder1.setView(np);
        builder1.setMessage(R.string.add_particip_msg);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                R.string.confirme_particip,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        final int nbrFois = np.getValue();
                        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        int a = 0;
                        while (a < nbrFois) {
                            writeNewUser1(user.getEmail());
                            a++;
                        }
                        }

                });

        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                R.string.reset_pass_no_btn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });




    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();


    }
```

**It works without problems. but when I add the code to remove values ​​from Carte contest_fragment code**

```
if (i == R.id.ParticipCarte1) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
        np.setMinValue(1);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Integer nbrcarte = dataSnapshot.child("carte").getValue(Integer.class);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    np.setMaxValue(nbrcarte);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder1.setView(np);
        builder1.setMessage(R.string.add_particip_msg);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                R.string.confirme_particip,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        final int nbrFois = np.getValue();
                        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("carte").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                            @Override
                            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                Integer carte = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                                mutableData.setValue(carte - nbrFois);

                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
                        });

                        int a = 0;
                        while (a < nbrFois) {
                            writeNewUser1(user.getEmail());
                            a++;
                        }
                        }

                });

        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                R.string.reset_pass_no_btn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });




    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();


    }
```

It works fine in the database but the application crashes

**And the logs indicate an error in another fragment:/**

**This is the entire logCat error :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.victorapp.winid, PID: 9923
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.victorapp.winid.Account_fragment$1.onDataChange(Account_fragment.java:85)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote
```

**Account Fragment code**

```
public class Account_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseUser user;
TextView profileTxt;
DatabaseReference reference;
DatabaseReference DeleteRef;
Button NbrCarte;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


public Account_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_fragment, container, false);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    profileTxt = rootView.findViewById(R.id.BonjourText);
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    NbrCarte = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCartes);

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.BtnDisconnect).setOnClickListener(this);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener(this);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPass).setOnClickListener(this);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCartes).setOnClickListener(this);




    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid());

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
            profileTxt.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.welcome_user) + username);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user =  mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String nbrcarte = dataSnapshot.child("carte").getValue().toString();
            NbrCarte.setText(nbrcarte + getString(R.string.cartes_title));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

        return rootView;

}

private void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    Intent SignOutIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    Account_fragment.this.startActivity(SignOutIntent);
}

private String email = "";
private void lostPassword (){
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builderLost = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builderLost.setTitle(R.string.reset_password);
    builderLost.setMessage(R.string.type_email);
    builderLost.setView(input);
    builderLost.setCancelable(true);
    builderLost.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.reset_pass_ok_btn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    email = input.getText().toString();
                    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                                getActivity().getText(R.string.email_send) + email,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                                getActivity().getText(R.string.email_err) + email,
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                }
            });

    builderLost.setNegativeButton(
            R.string.reset_pass_no_btn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert11 = builderLost.create();
    alert11.show();
}





public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.BtnDisconnect) {
        signOut();
    }
    if (i == R.id.btnDelete){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builderSuppr = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builderSuppr.setMessage(R.string.delete_alert_msg);
        builderSuppr.setCancelable(true);
        builderSuppr.setPositiveButton(
                R.string.reset_pass_ok_btn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        user.delete()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Compte supprimer.");
                                            DeleteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                                    .child("users").child(user.getUid());
                                            DeleteRef.removeValue();
                                            signOut();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });

        builderSuppr.setNegativeButton(
                R.string.reset_pass_no_btn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert11 = builderSuppr.create();
        alert11.show();
    }
    if (i == R.id.btnPass){
        lostPassword();
    }
    if (i == R.id.btnCartes){
        Intent CartesIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), referralActivity.class);
        Account_fragment.this.startActivity(CartesIntent);

    }

}
```

}

**EDIT : **

but what I can't understand is that when I remove this code:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("carte").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                            @Override
                            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                Integer carte = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                                mutableData.setValue(carte - nbrFois);

                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
                        });
```

The application no longer crashes. But I need this code x)

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What is the error in logcat?

Comment: error in LogCat indicates a String in another fragment

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.victorapp.winid, PID: 9923
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference `

Comment: What do you mean? Attach the error please

Comment: Where do you remove data from database?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I edit my comment

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin in my second code (in my question) just before the loop

Comment: while (a < nbrFois) {
                            writeNewUser1(user.getEmail());
                            a++;
                        }  This loop?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Yes this loop add entries to a Contest in my database and just above, there is the code to remove values of Carte.

Comment: You should see in logcat exactly which line has error

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Yes the error is in the line in another fragment. and the code of this line is : 

String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                profileTxt.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.welcome_user) + username);

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin but when I remove the code for delete values in Carte, the error disappear^^

Comment: Please attach the code that is relevant to the error, you have codes in your question, but you say error is in another fragment!

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin okay I edit my Question

Comment: Check if (datasnapshot.exists()) in first of onDataChange function

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin in Account_fragment ? or in my first code ?

Comment: in Account_fragment

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I put datasnapshot.exists above integer nbrcarte... but it still crashing

Comment: You put it as loop? put String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                profileTxt.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.welcome_user) + username); in the loop

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin and in have try in account_fragment still crashing

Comment: are u sure? because the code for string Username and the code of the loop is in 2 separate fragment who are not related

Comment: Your error is in account_fragment

Comment: Yes but I don't know why, because the error appears when I try to remove value of Carte in Contest_fragment (where there is the loop), but when I go to the Fragment Account_fragment there are no problems everything is displayed correctly.

Comment: You put if condition? It seems that datasnapshot is null

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I add an Edit in my question to explain a little better my problem

Comment: Your `onDataChange` may get called when the fragment is no longer (or not yet) attached to the view. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987649/why-getcontext-in-fragment-sometimes-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching a permanent listener in the `onCreateView` of your fragment. Since you never remove the listener, it keeps observing the data in the database as long as your app runs. Because of this, its `onDataChange` may get called when the fragment is no longer (or not yet) attached to the view.

For this reason you should take care to remove the listener when the fragment is detached from the activity. I'd recommend attaching the listener in `onStart()` and then removing it in `onStop`, but since you attach it in `onCreateView` you can also remove it in `onDestroyView`.

This requite the following steps:

1. Add a field in your fragment to track the listener:

   ```
   ValueEventListener mFirebaseListener
   ```
2. Set the listener field in the `onCreateView` or `onStart` when you attach it:

   ```
   mFirebaseListener = new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           Integer nbrcarte = dataSnapshot.child("carte").getValue(Integer.class);
           if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               np.setMaxValue(nbrcarte);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
           throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
       }
   });
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(mFirebaseListener);
   ```
3. Remove the listener in `onDestroyView` or `onStop`:

   ```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).removeEventListener(mFirebaseListener);
   ```

See:

- [Why getContext() in fragment sometimes returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987649/why-getcontext-in-fragment-sometimes-returns-null)
- the Android documentation on the [lifecycle of a fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=en-419#Creating)