# how to get value from firebase node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to get the value of isSeen node in Android Studio. The M6F2mJjQ8uGPXAynZzV is an id of the message and change message to message. And I want to get this value in an Adapter class.

Comment: What is the specific problem here?  Have you read the documentation?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So you want to get a `boolean`, convert to `string` and compare it to  `Another string`:**

**If that what you want then this is the answer for you:**

```
//this is the string that you want to compare against
String yourString = "true";

//this is your reference
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");


//make a listener
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //loop through the random key IDs

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        //get the boolean "isSeen"
        boolean isSeen = ds.child("isSeen").getValue(Boolean.class);

        //convert boolean to string
        String isSeenString = String.valueOf(isSeen);

        //compare isSeenString with your String

        if(isSeenString.equals(yourString)){
          //they are equal

         }else{
          //they are not equal

           }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

//add the listener
ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `isSeen` value then try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   Boolean isSeen = data.child("isSeen").getValue(Boolean.class);
                  }
            }

        @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                  throw databaseError.toException();
               }
          });
```

Iterate inside `Chats` node and then you can retrieve `isSeen`.

Comment: thanks for the response. just one more thing if I convert the value of isSeen from boolean to String then what it returns 1 or true. I need to compare with a String in if-else condition.

Comment: It returns true but of type string