# Reading from a Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read from a Firebase Database, I've read and looked everywhere, but I'm at a dead end.

Here's all that I've done.

Dependencies:

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.1'
>
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
>
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
>
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'

minSdkVersion: 15

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

then in a Button onClick method, I put the listener:

```
mDatabase.child("List").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String savedData = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "snapshot: " + savedData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error");
            }
    });
```

Here is a look at the Database.

[image]

Would appreciate the input.

Comment: will you please do `databaseError.printStackTrace()` or `databaseError.toString()` in `onCancelled` and tell us what it says

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I get nothing.
But I do get back null from the Database, as well as "Pasted" doesn't get added to it.

Comment: so the `onDataChange` is executing ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read a `String` value under `List`. But right under `List` there's no string value, rather there's a list of objects under there. To get the actual values, you'll need to navigate the JSON structure in your code.

Something like:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("List").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot tierSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d(TAG, tierSnapshot.getKey(); // "Tier 1", "Tier 1 B"
            for (DataSnapshot secondSnapshot: tierSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, secondSnapshot.getKey(); // "Tier 2", "Tier 2 B"

                String str = secondSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, str); // null, "2 B"

                Long num = secondSnapshot.getValue(long.class);
                Log.d(TAG, num); // 2, null

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Error", databaseError);
    }
});
```

An extra thing to note is that your values are of a different type, with the first one being the number `2`, while the second one is a string `"2 B"`. Hence the two `getValue()` calls, to get the specific type out of there. You could also just do `secondSnapshot.getValue()` and deal with the resulting object as you'd usually do (e.g. call `toString()` on it).